# Django freezes when reading data from request.body

Tags: django, python-requests

Let's say we have a simple Django view:

```
def my_view(request):
    content = request.body
    # some actions with content varible
    response = HttpResponse('<h1>It work!</h1>')
```

And a simple api client, let's say based on the requests library, sending malformed Django view data:

```
headers = dict()
headers['Accept'] = '*/*'
headers['Content-Length'] = '13409'
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-compressed'
headers['Expect'] = '100-continue'
headers['Host'] = '127.0.0.1:8000'
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Api client'
headers['content-encoding'] = 'gzip'

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api'

request_body = ''
r = requests.post(
    url,
    data=request_body,
    headers=headers
)
```

As you can see, request_body contains an empty string, but the Content-Length header stores the value 13409. When such a request arrives, Django hangs on the line reading request.body. No exceptions occur. How to solve this problem? I cannot influence the client, so the only thing I can do is rewrite the Django view. Django version 3.2.15 is used.

Comment: Are you sure it is the Django that is freezing? Because from what I think, it is probably the network layer which looks at the header length and waits till it gets that number of bytes. And since that many bytes are not sent, it is just waiting there.